# Blood Pressure Monitor from iOS/Android applications

Tags: android, ios, medical

I like to know the concept behind Blood Pressure Monitor applications in iOS/Android stores. Is it actually using any sensors to  monitor BP or it's a fun app to show random values ? What is the concept behind it? I surfed a lot but no luck. If anyone knows share with me.

Comment: Can you provide some examples?  Unless the apps are using a Bluetooth blood pressure sensor then they are probably just gimmicks

Comment: Just searched in playstore with key 'blood pressure app'.I don't know what  is behind it.

Comment: A quick search reveals two types of app, as I suspected - "prank" apps that don't really do anything and those that need an external Bluetooth or WiFi sensor or that require you to enter data manually or import from external services

Comment: What wil they do with BLE or WiFi?

Comment: Connect to a Blood Pressure Sensor e.g. http://www.withings.com/us/blood-pressure-monitor.html

Comment: This question seems to contain useful links: [Blood Pressure Monitor via Bluetooth/Internet in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405410/blood-pressure-monitor-via-bluetooth-internet-in-android). Nowadays the corresponding buzz word for returning relevant results or at least end-user's expectations would probably be [Smartwatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartwatch) or even [Smartwatch heart rate monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_rate_monitor)

Answer (score 1):

I guess these applications you mentioned don't measure blood pressure, but heart rate. It is impossible for the smartphone to measure blood pressure without an external device. It is however possible to measure a heart rate with a smartphone's camera. The concept is explained here:
http://www.ignaciomellado.es/blog/Measuring-heart-rate-with-a-smartphone-camera